# How do I get larger high-resolution images from my Epson Expression 10000XL scanner?

Tags: resolution, scanner, twain

I have an Epson 10000 XL scanner that I use at work. It's capable of scanning at a high resolution, but the problem is that when it's on its highest resolution setting, it limits the size of the image that it's capable of taking. However, I'm often scanning things that are larger than that maximum limit.

I've reached out to Epson, and they've suggested that I use Silverfast, from LaserSoft Imaging, in order to take higher-resolution images. I'm trying to get into contact with LaserSoft (it's been difficult getting folks to call me back), but in the meantime, is there a way or a software that would let me either a) take arbitrarily large scans at the highest resolution or b) take a series of images that could be stitched into a mosaic after the fact?

According to the documentation, any TWAIN-compliant scanner software should be able to run the scanner, but I'm having a tough time specifically finding other TWAIN-compliant applications that aren't just ScanFree.exe (my work is VERY particular about the software that gets downloaded).

Comment: Check XnView MP, it support TWAIN scanner (I use it) and practically can work with very huge images.

Comment: @RomeoNinov To clarify: is it capable of controlling the scanner, or can it only work with the images once it's been scanned?

Comment: It can "control" the scanner, can scan itself (via TWAIN). Plus it can edit, manage images. There is portable version you can use (no need to install)

Comment: Looks like XnView MP either uses the scanner's default software (and has the same issue) or limits the resolution to 1200 DPI, which is much lower than the scanner's capability. Any other suggestions?